# Serialize collection of base class to XML dynamically

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, xml-serialization

O hai there,

I want to serialize and object, which looks like this:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    [XmlArray("Entities"), XmlArrayItem("Entity")]
    public List<Base> Entities { get; set; }
}
```

I want to keep application as flexible as possible, thus setting manually derived class types in XmlArrayItem attribute is not an option, how can I do it dynamically, i.e. make serializer aware of all derived classes.

Btw I have already a class to get all directly derived types like `BaseDerived.DerivedClasses` and `XmlSerializer cs = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType(),BaseDerived.DerivedClasses);` doesnt work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a soultion, during serialization u can pretty much insert item attributes directly

So first you collect attributes like

```
    XmlAttributeOverrides xOver = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
    XmlAttributes xAttrs = new XmlAttributes();
    foreach (var cls in BaseDerived.DerivedClasses)
    {
        var attr = new XmlArrayItemAttribute(cls);
        xAttrs.XmlArrayItems.Add(attr);
    }
    xOver.Add(this.GetType(), BaseDerived.GetMemberName((Wrapper x) => x.Entities), xAttrs);
```

Btw:

```
public static string GetMemberName<T, TValue>(Expression<Func<T, TValue>> memberAccess)
{
    return ((MemberExpression)memberAccess.Body).Member.Name;
}
```

and then you just mention it in serialization:

```
    XmlSerializer cs = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType(), xOver);
```